# How to view page/column margins

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, margins

In Microsoft Word 2013 is there a way to view the margins so I can see where the limits of my current column are (one column or multiple columns)?

The closest I have gotten to this is by checking the `Show text boundaries` settings in the `Advanced` section of the `Options` window, however, this only outlines where the current text is but not the margins (limits/boundaries) of the column.

Answer (score 0):

You can get **crop marks** for the entire page in `File -> Options -> Advanced -> Show document content -> Show crop marks`. Unfortunately this doesn't show column limits, but helps with the page margins.